# How would I find this HashMap initializer in the documentation?

Tags: scala

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898925/446554) gives the following initialization of a HashMap.

```
scala> val m = collection.immutable.HashMap(0 -> 1, 2 -> 3)
m: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map((0,1), (2,3))
```

The official Scala [documentation for HashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap) gives this as the only `HashMap` constructor.

```
new HashMap()
```

Now, `new HashMap()` is clearly not used in the initialization above, but how would one read the official documentation and come to the knowledge that a list of tuples can be used to initialize a `HashMap`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the documentation for the class only.

`HashMap(0 -> 1, 2 -> 3)` is syntactic sugar for `HashMap.apply(0 -> 1, 2 -> 3)`, which is defined on the companion object. [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$)

To my knowledge all collections in the standard library have an `apply`-method for construction, but you have to look at the companion objects.

Comment: Click on the C or O at the top of the doc page to "go to companion".

Answer (score 0):

`AnyClassInScala(param: Int)` is equal `AnyClassInScala.apply(param: Int)`

any `1 -> 2` is equal `(1,2)` because both are `Tuple2` class.